# apply ntile function to list of data frames with different bucket sizes

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I would like to use the `ntile` function from `dplyr` or a similar function on a list of data frames but using a different `n` for each data frame. My list contains 150 data frames so a manual solution like the one below will not work.  How can I rewrite the code below to act on the list of data frames and return the list of data frames with the new column?

```
library(tidyverse)
iris_list=split(iris,iris$Species)

iris_setosa=iris_list[[1]]
iris_versicolor=iris_list[[2]]
iris_virginica=iris_list[[3]]
iris_setosa$n3=ntile(iris_setosa$Sepal.Length,3)
iris_versicolor$n5=ntile(iris_setosa$Sepal.Length,5)
iris_virginica$n7=ntile(iris_setosa$Sepal.Length,7)
```

The final result should be this

```
final_list=list(iris_setosa,iris_versicolor,iris_virginica)



head(final_list[[1]])
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species n3
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa  2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa  1
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  1
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa  1
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way that works

```
n_size=data.frame(Species=c("setosa ","versicolor","virginica"),size=c(3,5,7))
iris_bin=iris %>% inner_join(n_size,by="Species") %>%
                  group_by(Species)%>% 
                  mutate(bin=ntile(Sepal.Length,size[1])) %>% 
                  arrange(Species,Sepal.Length,bin)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, depending on what type of object you want in the end.

One way would be to use `base::expand.grid` and `purrr::pmap` like this:

```
percentiles = list(3,5,7)
iris_list %>% 
  map("Sepal.Length") %>% 
  expand.grid(percentiles) %>% 
  pmap(~ntile(..1,..2))
```

First, you want only the `Sepal.Length` variable of all your datasets, so you use `purrr::map` to get them.

Then, `expand.grid` creates a dataframe of all combinations of its parameters. Here, with 2 lists of 3 members, it would return a dataframe of 3x3=9 rows: `setosa 3`, `versicolor 3`, `virginica 3`, `setosa 5`, ...

Finally, `pmap` can iterate over the dataframe and apply the function `ntile`, with the first column (`iris_list`) as the first argument and the second column (`percentiles`) as the second argument. Unfortunately, purrr is very bad in dealing with names, but it seems that it is on purpose.

EDIT:

Your edit is somehow another question, so here is another answer:

```
iris_list %>%
   map(~mutate(.x, n3=ntile(Sepal.Length,3)), 
               n5=ntile(Sepal.Length,5)), n7=ntile(Sepal.Length,7)))
```

Comment: The code is tripling the size of my list and I need the original data frame back with the new column from ntile added.  How could I modify to get that result?

Comment: Thanks. This mostly works I will edit my question to make my desired solution clear I think I may haveexplained it poorly.

Comment: @tetime here is another answer

Comment: @tetime I guess this is not what you want yet. There is one thing I might wrongly have assumed, you do want n3, n5 and n7 for all 3 datasets, right?

Comment: @ Dan your previous answer worked the only thing it was missing was bringing the original data frame along which I need.  With your new solution I would have to manually input 150 lines in the mutate statement.  I'm sorry for the confusion,  thanks for the help.

Comment: @tetime in your edit, the additional column is named "n3", where are the other percentiles?

Comment: @ Dan Chaltiel that is just the first element of the final list, in general I will start with a list 150 data frames and 150 different percentiles. The result should be a list of 150 data frames with a new column added to each resulting from applying the ntile function for a specific percentile

Comment: Sorry but this is not clear. In your example, you have 3 data frames (one for each Specie) and 3 percentiles (3, 5, and 7). In practice, you say that you will have 150 data frames and 150 percentiles. If so, the result should be either a list of 150 data frames with 150 new columns or a list of 150*150=22500 data frames. In any case, your expected output doesn't match this. Could you clarify this point?

Comment: @ Dan yes "the result should be either a list of 150 data frames with 150 new columns" which is what the `final_list`  in my original post is, a list of 3 with 3 new columns. I think I am wasting your time I will try to modify your first answer I appreciate your time and help.